# 'Cannot store type: Xamarin.Forms.Entry' while login in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a mobile app, I did all database connections. When user enters its information it registers from register button then I redirect user to loginpage. But whenever I enter username and password then pressing login button, application goes into break mode and error is that

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Cannot store type: Xamarin.Forms.Entry'

Does anyone know the problem?  (I can send project if you want to ,as well)
RegUserTable.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;
using SQLitePCL;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HealNow
{
    class RegUserTable
    {
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Dateofbirth { get; set; }
        public string Weight { get; set; }
        public string Height { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs ( this is my login page)

```
    using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.IO;
using SQLitePCL;
using static System.Environment;

namespace HealNow
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dbpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Userdatabase.db");
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
            var enter = db.Table<RegUserTable>().Where(u => u.Username.Equals(logUsername.Text) && u.Password.Equals(logPassword)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (enter != null)
            {
                App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new WelcomePage());
            }
            else
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {

                    var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Error", "Incorrect username or password", "Okay", "Cancel");
                    if (result)
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
                    else
                    {
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
                    }
                } ) ;
            }
        }

        private async void Button_Clicked_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Signup());
        }
    }
}
```

Signup.xaml.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;
using SQLitePCL;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using static System.Environment;

namespace HealNow
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Signup : ContentPage
    {
        public Signup()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dbpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Userdatabase.db");
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
            db.CreateTable<RegUserTable>();

            var item = new RegUserTable()
            {
                Username = regUsername.Text,
                Email = regEmail.Text,
                Password = regPassword.Text,
                Dateofbirth = regDob.Text,
                Weight = regWeight.Text,
                Height = regHeight.Text,

            };
            db.Insert(item);
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {

                var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Login Successful", "Redirecting to LoginPage","Okay", "Cancel");
                if (result)
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
            } );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an error while clicking Login button inside the MainPage,I can send project to you if you want @Cfun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

```
u.Password.Equals(logPassword)
```

should be

```
u.Password.Equals(logPassword.Text)
```